# SQL performance optimization. Which query will be better?

Tags: sql-server

I have a select satetment which has a join with a greater than or equal to condition.

Which of the following query will be have a better performace

```
SELECT Id.[Id],id.[IdentityGuid],Id.LastUpdated, Id.[DisabledDate], Id.[DeletedDate], ip.[Hash]
                FROM [IDTable] id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PHTable ip ON ip.IdentityId = id.Id AND ip.type= 3 AND ip.[ModifiedDate]>=
                CASE WHEN @modifiedSince is not null then @modifiedSince ELSE ip.[ModifiedDate]
WHERE id.EtId = @tId AND (@modifiedSince is null OR id.[LastUpdated] >= @modifiedSince OR ip.[ModifiedDate]>= ip.[ModifiedDate])
```

OR

```
SELECT Id.[Id],id.[IdentityGuid],Id.LastUpdated, Id.[DisabledDate], Id.[DeletedDate], ip.[Hash]
                    FROM [IDTable] id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN PHTable ip ON ip.IdentityId = id.Id AND ip.type= 3 AND (@modifiedSince is null OR ip.[ModifiedDate]>= @modifiedSince)
    WHERE id.EtId = @tId AND (@modifiedSince is null OR id.[LastUpdated] >= @modifiedSince OR ip.[ModifiedDate]>= ip.[ModifiedDate])
```

Means Using Case when statement like this

```
ip.[ModifiedDate]>=CASE WHEN @modifiedSince is not null then @modifiedSince ELSE ip.[ModifiedDate] END
```

OR just like this

```
(@modifiedSince is null OR ip.[ModifiedDate]>= @modifiedSince)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pull all the records when the parameter `@modifiedSince` is `NULL` (ie) optional filter.

First of all both will not produce same result when you have `NULL` values in `ip.[ModifiedDate]` column

If there will not be any `NULL` in `ip.[ModifiedDate]` values then I think the second approach looks bit cleaner. Performance wise both should have similar execution time

Comment: Would u pls help me in making a query for generating the same reult using case when

Comment: `ip.[ModifiedDate]>= CASE WHEN @modifiedSince is not null then @modifiedSince END` Will this give me the sme result??

Comment: @Manu - You can do something like this `isnull(ip.[ModifiedDate],'1900-01-01') >= CASE
                                                  WHEN @modifiedSince IS NOT NULL THEN @modifiedSince
                                                  ELSE isnull(ip.[ModifiedDate],'1900-01-01')
                                                END` but why do you need it when there is a easier approach. This will not any index present in `ModifiedDate` column